# How to read pinout of this SPDT relay G8N-1F

Tags: relay, schematics, pinout, spdt

**Introduction:**

The direction indicators of the car (Honda FR-V) are not working anymore. I managed to get the ICU (integrated control unit) out of the fuse box beneath the steering wheel. Hell of a job in such confined space. There are 2 relays of which I think 2 are for the direction indicators. Anyway. I suspect the relays are at the end of their life time (already after just 140,000 km on the car!!) and wish to replace them.

**Question:**
[image]

[This is the datasheet](http://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g8n.pdf).
The relays in question is an Omron G8N-1F.
How do I read this schematic? It is a SPDT relay. Which pins get connected when the operating voltage of 12Vdc is applied at what pin? Probably a newbie question. From what I read pin 4 and 1 are connected as normally closed. When current is running from pin 2 to 5, pin 1 gets connected to 3. Am I right? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pins 2 and 5 are the coil. Pin 4 (also called Normally Closed, or NO) connects to pin 1 (known as the Wiper, W) when the coil is not energised. When it is, W connects to pin 3 (Normally Open, NO).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick answer. As I suspected. Great to have you verify it. The module costs like ~€400,- if I need to replace it. So I am extra careful trying to fix it.

Comment: you should be able to get replacement relays for a few bucks - but I hate to tell you, the chances of two of these things being blown is vanishingly small. In my experience Omron relays are right up there with death and taxes in terms of reliability. Anyway, if you have a 12V supply, you can test them with that and a multimeter on the bench.

Comment: They might not be "left" and "right," but something like "blink" and "direction."  I wouldn't assume they're both bad...depending on the circuit, one might be enough.

Comment: @dmb I found a topic on the net where others seem to have the same issue. He states: `It was one of the G8N-1F`: https://hondakarma.com/threads/honda-fr-v-indicators-faulty.6466/live#post-111603 So I got good hopes :)

Comment: you can't tell until you try - good luck!

Comment: I find that the direction indicator relays in my BMW never seem to wear out.